# How to transform a list of 3-tuples (Iterator<Item = (K0, K1, V)>) into a map of maps (HashMap<K0, HashMap<K1, V>>)?

Tags: rust

The title above should be enough to explain the question, if not, then the following code snippet will.

```rust
fn transform<K0, K1, V, I>(input: I) -> HashMap<K0, HashMap<K1, V>>
where
  K0: Hash + Eq,
  K1: Hash + Eq,
  I: IntoIterator<Item = (K0, K1, V)>,
{
  // what is the most elegant (preferably functional) way to do this?
}
```

Comment: uhm, just out of curiosity, why dont use instead `HashMap<(K0, K1), V>`?

Comment: @Netwave I sometimes need to look up a set of `K1` from `K0`.

Comment: Questions asking for opinion-based matters (like what's "more elegant") are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

One "functional" way can do it is with `fold`. But I prefer the explicit loop.

```
fn transform2<K0, K1, V, I>(input: I) -> HashMap<K0, HashMap<K1, V>>
where
    K0: Hash + Eq,
    K1: Hash + Eq,
    I: IntoIterator<Item = (K0, K1, V)>,
{
    input
        .into_iter()
        .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut h, (k0, k1, v)| {
            h.entry(k0).or_default().insert(k1, v);
            h
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop would do in this case:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn transform<K0, K1, V, I>(input: I) -> HashMap<K0, HashMap<K1, V>>
where
  K0: Hash + Eq,
  K1: Hash + Eq,
  I: IntoIterator<Item = (K0, K1, V)>,
{
    let mut result_map = HashMap::new();
    for (k0, k1, v) in input {
        result_map.entry(k0).or_insert_with(HashMap::new).insert(k1, v);
    }
    result_map
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1df97bf41f96fb4d78fe68b33a691c01)

Comment: I like `or_insert_with` over `or_default` like the other answer has, as it feels "better" to me.  The other gets a default empty `HashMap`, whereas this explicitly makes what you want.  This may be wordier, but it's more explicit, which I like.

Answer (score 0):

User Hyeonu from the Rust forum provided an excellent answer ([link](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-transform-a-list-of-3-tuples-iterator-item-k0-k1-v-into-a-map-of-maps-hashmap-k0-hashmap-k1-v/66257/2?u=ksxgithub)):

```rust
fn transform<K0, K1, V, I>(input: I) -> HashMap<K0, HashMap<K1, V>>
where
  K0: Hash + Eq,
  K1: Hash + Eq,
  I: IntoIterator<Item = (K0, K1, V)>,
{
    let mut m = HashMap::<K0, HashMap<K1, V>>::new();
    for (k0, k1, v) in input {
        m.entry(k0).or_default().insert(k1, v);
    }
    m
}
```

Comment: oh, you actually came with the same. For some reason it couldnt elide the type for default when I tried it.

Comment: Not me, its another person in the Rust forum

Comment: So, if you try to compile it in the playground it will not compile. It cannot elide the type for the default

Comment: Ok, I will update this answer and notify the original author. Thank you.

Comment: @Netwave so the author responded. The code snippet was missing explicit type annotation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about "Most elegant", but here's a functional solution:

```
input.into_iter().fold (HashMap::new(), |mut m, (k0, k1, v)| {
    m.entry (k0).or_insert_with (|| HashMap::new()).insert (k1, v); m
})
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdf33b2ddda0ea715b363f7aab2c42d5)

Comment: uhm, this is the same solution as Michael, plus some other stylish  adjustments (which actually seems worst)

Comment: @Netwave Michael hadn't yet posted his solution when I wrote mine…

Comment: yeah, sometimes the web updates takes some time :(